# My MERN app is deployed on Namecheap / cPanel but it's not accessing Mongo Atlas DB

Tags: reactjs, deployment, cpanel, mern, namecheap

#### ISSUE

My app is hosted on Namecheap shared hosting, but it doesn't connect to my Mongo Atlas DB.

#### DETAILS

I'm very new to this, and have only deployed to Heroku.  I tried to use them at first, but I couldn't figure out how to get the image file upload/retrieval working with S3.

So I'm trying Namecheap.

Anyways on the cPanel file directory, my app is in: `/home/username/repositories/myapp`

I also ran the `npm run build` command locally, and placed the contents of the newly-created `/build/` directory inside cPanel's `/home/username/public_html`

I'm almost certain that it doesn't have to be done that way, but so far that's the only thing that gets my actual website to render on the browser.

I used cPanel's "Setup NodeJS App" menu to put my app up, and set the "Application Starter File" to `server.js`

*My server.js file*

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const dotenv = require('dotenv');
const cors = require('cors');
const path = require('path');

// Activate dotenv for secure keys
dotenv.config();


// Middleware to recognize incoming Request Object as a JSON object
app.use(express.json());


// Local file storage
app.use('/uploads', express.static('uploads'));


// Bind Routes
const commissions = require('./routes/api/commissions');
const projects = require('./routes/api/projects');
const users = require('./routes/api/users');
// Use Routes
app.use(cors());
app.use('/commissions', commissions);
app.use('/projects', projects);
app.use('/users', users);


// Mongo connect
mongoose
  .connect(process.env.URI || process.env.MONGO_URI, {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
    useCreateIndex: true
  })
  .then(() => console.log("Connected to MongoDB"))
  .catch(err => console.log(err));


// For Deployment
if(process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
  app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'client', 'build')));

  app.get('*', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'client', 'build', 'index.html'));
  });
};


// Run server
const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;
app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Server started on port ${port}`));
```

I ran NPM install in cPanel (as well as a script in my package.json to run `npm install` on the client-side) hoping both of those would enable my app to work (like in development).

I also checked my Mongo Atlas IP Whitelist but it's already allowing for `0.0.0.0/0` (from my heroku deployment).

Also, the namecheap support staff opened Port 5000 for me, (I read in another forum that this was the solution for someone with a similar problem) but that did not work for me either.

Answer (score 1):

Solved by:

- Adding my Shared Hosting IP address (located in cPanel) to Mongo Atlas IP Whitelist
- Contacting cPanel support and having them open the appropriate backend ports
- Changing the NodeJS version of my app on cPanel's "Setup NodeJS App" menu

The biggest thing was the Node version.  Node has many versions, but as of this post cPanel only has the following Node Version options:

```
12.19.1
11.15.0
10.22.0
9.11.2
8.17.0
6.17.1
```

My particular version is none of those, so I was informed to just select the highest version available.  But that's what was breaking the connection to my Mongo Atlas DB.

I tested each of those options, and the one that worked was `8.17.0`.